# Wait function on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to wait until  "next" button is pressed then continue

```
child.addChild(tmp);
childrenAdded.Push(tmp);
neighbor.GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = null;                     
-WAIT UNTIL CLICK ON NEXT BUTTON THEN CONTINUE-

toExpand.Push(tmp);
```

any idea? I tried:

```
while(true) {
    if(GUI.Button(Rect(500,680 ,100,30),"Next"))
        break
    }
```

But it doesn't work; it freezes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of waiting, you can just have your code called when the button is clicked, like this:

```
void OnGUI() {
    if(GUI.Button(Rect(500,680 ,100,30),"Next"))                        
        toExpand.Push(tmp);
    }
}
```

If possible, consider using Unity 4.6 or later so you can use the [new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui?playlist=17111) which is much easier work with.

Comment: As he is using GUI.Button I think he already is in OnGUI() or Unity would throw him an exception. He's problems seem that he needs to active some loot by clicking the button and deactivate it after another click.

Comment: I agree that the problem is not about the OnGUI itself, I edited the answer to make clear it's about putting the code in the callback of the click (instead of waiting for it programatically)

Comment: I already edited my answer too because I've realised that may I misunderstood his real problem, it needs a better explanation of "
this is the goal I want to achieve"... Maybe he just need to wait something to be finished and the answer here is to go with coroutines instead of the button itself ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Toggle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Toggle.html) button instead of button so you controll a boolean with toogle and loops what you need in your Update or LateUpdate function like this:

```
private Rect myRect = new Rect(500,680 ,100,30);
private bool myToggle = false;

void OnGui() {
    myToggle = GUI.Toogle(myRect, myToggle, "Next");
}

void Update() {
    if(myToggle){
        // what I need to create while true;
    }
}
```

*Note that is not a good practice to create a new Rect every OnGUI cycle because it runs more than once per frame and it will create a performance issue.*

Reading your code again may I could've misinterpreted your needing so if you could clarify what you really what your code to do would be easier to help.

Also, if you just need a "wizard" like sequence of actions I suggest you to take a look on [delegates](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/delegates) and use something like this:

```
delegate void MyDelegate();
private MyDelegate myDelegate;
private Rect myRect = new Rect(500,680 ,100,30);

void Start () {  
    myDelegate = FirstFunction; 
}

void FirstFunction() {
    // will execute until next button is clicked
}

void SecondFunction() {
    // will execute after next button is clicked
}

void OnGui() {
    if(GUI.Button(myRect, "Next")) {
        myDelegate = SecondFunction; 
    }
}
```